# Pass Lightning input iteration value by index of String array

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightninginput, indexing, getfieldvalue

I have a lightning component where I dynamically generate some columns and some input fields. I have a String Array as attribute. How do I get the index of the array to pass the value. I tried below but this gives me an expression error.

Attribute

```
<aura:attribute name="searchKeywordArr" type="String[]" description="store search input"/>
```

Iteration

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.colData}" var="obj" indexVar="index">
                            <td role="gridcell">
                                <lightning:input 
                                                 value="{!v.searchKeywordArr[v.indexVar]}"
                                                 required="false"
                                                 placeholder="{!obj.label + '...'}"
                                                 aura:id="{!obj.Id}"
                                                 label="{!obj.label}"
                                                 variant="label-hidden"/>
                                
                            </td>
                        </aura:iteration>
```

Comment: @AlbaRivas I found the solution and posted this as an answer please  remove your link because this is misleading. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was trying to give a solution to the value="{!v.searchKeywordArr[v.indexVar]}" bit which is what I understood that you had problems with, but ok, removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for an anwer. The following works

Component:

```
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.colData}" var="obj" indexVar="index">
        <lightning:input type="text" name="{!index}" value="{!obj}" label="Lightning Input" onchange="{!c.update}"/>
     </aura:iteration>
```

Javascriptcontroller:

```
update : function(component,event){
        var index = event.getSource().get('v.name');
            alert('index' + index);  
        var value = event.getSource().get('v.value');
              alert('value' + value);  
    }
```